# Single jquery POST with multiple buttons and response actions

Tags: jquery

I'm sending the same POST values multiple times. Is it possible to set the POST values once only and use it multiple times with different buttons?

example:
A complete code:

```
  $('#btn1').click(function(){   
        $.post("my.php",
            {
              status:$('input[name=radio]:checked').val(),
              name:$( '#name' ).val(),
              subject:$( '#subject' ).val()
            },
          function(response) {
            //do something with response...
          });
  });
```

I would like to do something like this:

```
function getPost(){
   $.post("my.php",
   {
     status:$('input[name=radio]:checked').val(),
     name:$( '#name' ).val(),
     subject:$( '#subject' ).val()
     },
}

      $('#btn1').click(function(){   
            getPost();
              function(response) {
                //do AAAAA...
              });
      });

      $('#btn2').click(function(){   
            getPost();
              function(response) {
                //do BBBBB...
              });
      });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like that, may be

```
function getData(){
  return {
     status:$('input[name=radio]:checked').val(),
     name:$( '#name' ).val(),
     subject:$( '#subject' ).val()
    }
}

$('#btn1').click(function(){   
  $.post(url, getData(), function( response ){ /* do AAA with respone */ });
});

$('#btn2').click(function(){   
  $.post(url, getData(), function( response ){ /* do BBB with response */ });
});
```

Comment: @Anne: I updated my answer. If I understand you right - response values returns as argument of callback function in $.post.

Comment: 1. `processData(response);` is confusing unnecessary code - according to OP question, `function(response) { ... }` is sufficient. 2. It should be `#btn2` in second selector for click event handlers.